# Can there exist a non-linear unitary map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a complex Hilbert space with inner product $( \cdot, \cdot)$. Can there exist a 'unitary function' $U : V \to V$ which is *not* linear? In other words, does
$$(Uv, Uw) = (v,w) \ \ \text{ for all } v, w \in V$$
necessarily imply that $U$ is linear?

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample; that was the kind of thing I was worried about. For those who can't see it because the response it was threaded under has been deleted, DGHE wrote the following: Consider $V = \ell^2(\mathbb{N, C})$ with the standard Hilbert basis $(e_n)$ and $T$ defined by $T(e_n) = e_{2n}$. This is an isometry which is not surjective.

Comment: @AlexR, you might consider undeleting your response. It is a helpful addition to the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible. Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a orthonormal basis of $V$. Then $\{Ue_i\}_{i\in I}$ is also a orthonormal set. Let $W$ denotes the orthogonal complement of $\text{span}(\{Ue_i\}_{i\in I})$. For each $v\in V$, since $(Uv,Ue_i)=(v,e_i)$, $Uv$ must be of form $\sum_{i\in I}(v,e_i)Ue_i+w$, where $w\in W$. But we also have $(v,v)=(Uv,Uv)=(\sum_{i\in I}(v,e_i)Ue_i,\sum_{i\in I}(v,e_i)Ue_i)+(w,w)$ and $(v,v)=(\sum_{i\in I}(v,e_i)Ue_i,\sum_{i\in I}(v,e_i)Ue_i)$, which forces that $(w,w)=0$ and consequently $w=0$. Thus $Uv$ must be $\sum_{i\in I}(v,e_i)Ue_i$, which is apparently linear.

Comment: Do you mean "For each $v \in W$..."?

Comment: @SimonS  There's some notation conflict, I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clarify.

Comment: Does this hold for general inner product spaces?

Comment: @IvánMauricioBurbano eh, I think general linear inner product spaces are none other than Hilbert spaces....

Comment: Well, Hilbert spaces are complete inner product spaces. However, your comment made me realize that your proof applies to general inner product spaces. Indeed, since every unitary operator is bounded and thus uniformly continuous, it can be extended to the unique Hilbert space extension. Then your proof applies, the extension is linear, and the original operator must also be linear. In this Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator there is a more direct proof. I developed the calculations in detail in https://ideabrewery683073326.wordpress.com/2019/01/11/inner-products/